# How do I put a JSP file under /web/build/

Tags: jsp, netbeans, glassfish

I'm new to JSP and netbeans, I'm trying to make a simple communication between index.jsp to 02.jsp. I created both of them under WEB-INF folder. After I built the 02.jsp file, (under /WEB-INF), How do I add it to /web/build/ folder? Because Glassfish seems to always check that folder for servlets. Do I always have to manually move them over?

Thanks.

Comment: Regular JSP's should NOT be under the WEB-INF folder (unless you are using some sort of framework). Put them in "*Web Pages*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files in `/WEB-INF` (and `/META-INF`) are not publicly accessible. You don't want that the enduser can view for example `web.xml`, do you? Only servlets (such as in MVC frameworks) are able to forward requests to there by `RequestDispatcher` (see for an example als [our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info))

Put files which need to be publicly accessible *outside* `/WEB-INF` folder.